# Is SecureString a write-only class?

Tags: c#, .net, security, securestring

I recently discovered SecureString and it seems to fit a perfect application where I want to basically initialize a static secret string at the beginning of an application, and then make it read-only and use it throughout the life of the application(as a portion of a hash).

I'm having trouble understanding how to even make use of the SecureString class.. From what I can tell, you can set the SecureString, but there is no way to compare the value or retrieve the value in any way.

What is the purpose of this class if it's write-only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ways here, a way to convert it to a securestring and from a securestring. Of course the whole point of storing it in a securestring is to prevent it from being in memory in the first place.

```
        #region SecureString Manipulation
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a Securestring to a regular string (not considered best practice, but make sure it's not in memory if you can help it)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="securePassword">Password stored in a secure string</param>
    /// <returns>regular string of securestring password</returns>
    public static string ConvertToUnsecureString(this System.Security.SecureString securePassword)
    {
        if (securePassword == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("securePassword");

        IntPtr unmanagedString = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            unmanagedString = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(securePassword);
            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(unmanagedString);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(unmanagedString);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pass a text password to this function to return a SecureString (doesn't store the password in memory)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">Text version of a password</param>
    /// <returns>SecureString of a password (not readable by memory)</returns>
    public static SecureString ConvertToSecureString(this string password)
    {
        if (password == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("password");

        var secure = new SecureString();
        foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray())
            secure.AppendChar(c);
        return secure;
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not write-only: you can retrieve a regular .NET `String` from the `SecureString` by using the [Marshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) class:

```
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(secureString);
string str = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(ptr);
Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(ptr);
return str;
```

Note that this allocates unmanaged memory, so you need to be sure to free it (with [`Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.zerofreebstr.aspx)) to avoid leaks. And it should go without saying that once you've converted it to a .NET String, you lose the benefits of SecureString (the String will remain in memory until it's GC'ed, it may be paged to disk, etc.).

The purpose of the SecureString class is that you can use it in APIs where the privacy of user data (e.g., passwords or credit card numbers) should be protected (e.g., if your application crashes and a minidump is saved to disk). A handful of classes in the .NET Framework (e.g., [PasswordBox.SecurePassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.securepassword.aspx)) take a SecureString object in order to avoid exposing this data.

Comment: +1 for the "goes without saying" part, though at the moment support in the framework isn't what it could be. I'd like to see an easy way to at least convert one directly to an sha1 or bcrypt hash to at least cover passwords.

Comment: @Joel completely agree. My secret string is just a portion that goes into a hash to make it a bit more unique. If there were a way to get a hash of it, then it'd still serve the purpose I need

Comment: Is there any way to extract characters from a `SecureString` without them ever being assembled together in memory?  Reading characters from a `SecureString` individually, either by index or via `IEnumerator<Char>`, would seem more secure than marshalling to a BSTR.

Comment: @supercat: No, there is not. The current implementation of SecureString only supports adding a character at a time, not retrieving. (And the underlying Win32 method, RtlEncryptMemory, has a minimum block size of 8 bytes, so any IEnumerable<char> implementation would have to decrypt at least four chars at a time.)

Comment: @BradleyGrainger: From a performance standpoint, reading a string a character at a time by fetching a block, decrypting it, taking one character from that, and discarding the rest, would obviously not be terribly efficient, but since code will generally spend most of its time doing things other than handling secure strings, I wouldn't think that would be a major issue.  Further, if a string is being read by the thread in which it was created, having it cache the current four-character block would ease that performance bottleneck...

Comment: ...without ever having to have the entire string stored in the clear [further, there's no particular reason the four-character cache would have to be stored in eight consecutive bytes of memory].  Having `SecureString` return a `String` would make it pointless, but other ways of reading it from managed code could be just as secure--if not moreso--than marshalling to a BSTR.